# Filter for complete groups of 4 out of a 4000+ image set

Tags: r, image-processing, filtering

I have a dataset of 4000+ images. For the purpose of figuring out the code, I moved a small batch of them to another folder.

The files look like this:

```
    folder

    r01c01f01p01-ch3.tiff
    r01c01f01p01-ch4.tiff
    r01c01f02p01-ch1.tiff
    r01c01f03p01-ch2.tiff
    r01c01f03p01-ch3.tiff
    r01c01f04p01-ch2.tiff
    r01c01f04p01-ch4.tiff
    r01c01f05p01-ch1.tiff 
    r01c01f05p01-ch2.tiff
    r01c01f06p01-ch2.tiff
    r01c01f06p01-ch4.tiff
    r01c01f09p01-ch3.tiff
    r01c01f09p01-ch4.tiff
    r01c01f10p01-ch1.tiff
    r01c01f10p01-ch4.tiff
    r01c01f11p01-ch1.tiff
    r01c01f11p01-ch2.tiff
    r01c01f11p01-ch3.tiff
    r01c01f11p01-ch4.tiff
    r01c02f10p01-ch1.tiff
    r01c02f10p01-ch2.tiff
    r01c02f10p01-ch3.tiff
    r01c02f10p01-ch4.tiff
```

I cannot remove the name prior to the -ch# as that information is important.

What I want to do is to filter the folder of images, and move/keep only sets (ie: r01c02f10p01) which have all four ch values (ch1-4).

For background: I use a different script to merge the images into a composite relies on the fact that we have a complete ch1, ch2, ch3, and ch4 suffix on each image, and that they are in batches of four. (This code is used in an image processing software called Fiji, rather than R.)

In trying to filter the images, the set originally included a fifth channel (ch5). I was able to remove the all images with ch5 from the original folder like this.

```
    ##Create folder variable which has all image files 
     setwd("/Desktop/Nov 5/")
          folder = list.files("/Desktop/Nov5/")
    folder <- list.files(getwd())

    ##Create final2 variable which has all image files ending in ch5
    final2 <- dir(path="/Desktop/Nov5/", pattern="ch5") 

    ##Remove final2 from folder
    file.remove(folder,final2)
```

In trying to address the issue of filtering only complete sets, I'd thought that doing something like this:

```
    ch1 <- dir(path="/Desktop/cp/complete//", pattern="ch1")

    ch2 <- dir(path="/Desktop/cp/complete//", pattern="ch2")

    ch3 <- dir(path="/Desktop/cp/complete//", pattern="ch3")

    ch4 <- dir(path="/Desktop/cp/complete//", pattern="ch4")
```

And applying the file.remove function, similar to below, might work.

```
    final2 <- dir(path="/Desktop/cp1/Images//", pattern="ch5") 
    file.remove(folder,final2)
```

However, creating new variables for each ch value fragments out each file. I am unsure how to use these to actually distinguish whether an individual image has all four ch values to meaningfully filter my images in the original (or a new folder). The other sources I've seen have issues that don't quite match this problem.

Another thread had a suggestion of converting files into a data.frame, but that doesn't actually allow me to manipulate the image files in the folder. I need to move/filter the files, not just display a list of the correct ones unfortunately. That was as follows:

```
    library(dplyr)

    ch_set <- 1:4

    files_to_keep <- data.frame(filename = files, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
      tidyr::extract(filename, into = c("group", "ch"), regex = "                (^[\\w\\d]+)\\-ch(\\d)", remove = FALSE) %>%
      mutate(ch = as.numeric(ch)) %>%
      group_by(group) %>% 
      filter(all(ch_set %in% ch))

    files_to_keep
```

To summarize: I expect to filter files from a random assortment without complete ch values (ie: maybe only ch1 and ch2, or ch3 and ch4), to an assortment of files which only contains those with complete ch1, ch2, ch3, and ch4 images.

Note: I am still very new to R, so I can clarify if some of the language describing the issue is off.

Comment: To keep things minimal (see [mcve]) and separate concerns between the two questions, you can edit this one to just the tasks that start at having a list of filenames that you need to move, so you can focus on that task here

Comment: I edited to try to par it down, but functionally speaking the pair of tasks are pretty tightly intertwined. I'm more concerned about properly filtering things, and I edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

#Input data
dirnames <- data.frame(flenames = c("r01c01f01p01-ch3.tiff", "r01c01f01p01-ch4.tiff", "r01c01f02p01-ch1.tiff", "r01c01f03p01-ch2.tiff", 
                                    "r01c01f03p01-ch3.tiff", "r01c01f04p01-ch2.tiff", "r01c01f04p01-ch4.tiff", "r01c01f05p01-ch1.tiff", 
                                    "r01c01f05p01-ch2.tiff", "r01c01f06p01-ch2.tiff", "r01c01f06p01-ch4.tiff", "r01c01f09p01-ch3.tiff", 
                                    "r01c01f09p01-ch4.tiff", "r01c01f10p01-ch1.tiff", "r01c01f10p01-ch4.tiff", "r01c01f11p01-ch1.tiff", 
                                    "r01c01f11p01-ch2.tiff", "r01c01f11p01-ch3.tiff", "r01c01f11p01-ch4.tiff", "r01c02f10p01-ch1.tiff", 
                                    "r01c02f10p01-ch2.tiff", "r01c02f10p01-ch3.tiff", "r01c02f10p01-ch4.tiff"))

#To get actual input data in the format above
#Presuming this script is being executed from the directory where the `tiff` files are stored
dirnames <- data.frame(flenames = list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "*.tiff"))

#Creating a column for the leading string, using which we can group the channels (stored in an accompanying column)
#Then grouping by the leading string, and nesting the channel and filename columns thereunder.
#Using the length of the nested tibble to consider files for removal.
#If the nested tibble contains 4 channels (i.e. length == 4), then keep. Else discard.
dirnames %<>% 
  mutate(fc1 = str_extract(flenames, ".+(?=\\-)")) %>% #Leading string
  mutate(fc2 = str_extract(flenames, "(?<=\\-)\\w+")) %>% #Channel string
  select(-c(flenames)) %>%
  group_by(fc1) %>%  #Grouping
  nest(fc3 = fc2) %>% #Nesting
  mutate(keep_val = if(length(unlist(fc3)) == 4){"Y"} else{"N"}) %>% #Checking to keep/discard
  unnest(fc3) %>% #Unnesting to get back original data frame
  mutate(flename = paste0(fc1, "-", fc2, ".tiff")) %>% #Getting the original filename back
  ungroup(.) %>% 
  select(flename, keep_val) #Reordering data frame

#For loop to iterate through data frame, and issue file.remove() commands as necessary
for(i in 1:nrow(dirnames)){
  if(dirnames$keep_val[i] == "N"){
    cat("Removing file ", paste0(dirnames$flename[i]), "\n")
    file.remove(dirnames$flename[i])
  } else{
    cat("Keeping file ", paste0(dirnames$flename[i]), "\n")
  }
}

# Removing file  r01c01f01p01-ch3.tiff 
# Removing file  r01c01f01p01-ch4.tiff 
# Removing file  r01c01f02p01-ch1.tiff 
# Removing file  r01c01f03p01-ch2.tiff 
# Removing file  r01c01f03p01-ch3.tiff 
# Removing file  r01c01f04p01-ch2.tiff 
# Removing file  r01c01f04p01-ch4.tiff 
# Removing file  r01c01f05p01-ch1.tiff 
# Removing file  r01c01f05p01-ch2.tiff 
# Removing file  r01c01f06p01-ch2.tiff 
# Removing file  r01c01f06p01-ch4.tiff 
# Removing file  r01c01f09p01-ch3.tiff 
# Removing file  r01c01f09p01-ch4.tiff 
# Removing file  r01c01f10p01-ch1.tiff 
# Removing file  r01c01f10p01-ch4.tiff 
# Keeping file  r01c01f11p01-ch1.tiff 
# Keeping file  r01c01f11p01-ch2.tiff 
# Keeping file  r01c01f11p01-ch3.tiff 
# Keeping file  r01c01f11p01-ch4.tiff 
# Keeping file  r01c02f10p01-ch1.tiff 
# Keeping file  r01c02f10p01-ch2.tiff 
# Keeping file  r01c02f10p01-ch3.tiff 
# Keeping file  r01c02f10p01-ch4.tiff
```

Explanations for the code are included in the comments within.

For actual use, you could get a list of input files with something like `dirnames <- list.files(pattern = "*.tiff")`.

**Note**: I had commented out `file.remove()` for my sample output.

**Note**: this code filters for four files exactly (at the moment). Just change the comparison operator in this line `mutate(keep_val = if(length(unlist(fc3)) == 4){"Y"} else{"N"})` and/or the number after it to select at different thresholds (e.g., all files that have at least 4 channels' data available).

It'll probably be very slow depending on how big the files are, considering you've mentioned you have 4000+ files. Maybe this is a task for the shell?

I hope I've understood your question correctly, and provided a workable solution here.

Comment: I think this is really close! For the first block, I would need to edit it though, as I have the actual files to work with. This should be done by         dirnames <- data.frame(flenames = folder)
I think. folder is the variable that contains all of the files. When I do this, I start getting the following error, however: "Error in unlist(fc3) : object 'fc3' not found." Should fc3 just be swapped for fc2?

Comment: If you can point out the shortcomings, we should be able to optimize things further.

Comment: I edited my previous comment to clarify. Thank you!

Comment: I also tried  to edit such that        dirnames <- list.files(pattern = "*.tiff"), and that seems to have resulted in a different error.  " Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"". For the part applying the loop, it also says "Error in 1:nrow(dirnames) : argument of length 0".

Comment: I just made some edits to the code. You should not be getting that error concerning `unlist(fc3)` if you have all the necessary packages in order. And I also updated the code with a way to get the dirnames `data.frame` set up directly `dirnames <- data.frame(flenames = list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "*.tiff"))`.

Comment: I just tried out the whole thing with some made up `tiff` files, and it works fine. Just check the updated code again, and give it a try. Just make sure to run this code from the directory where the `tiff` files are located.

Comment: I double checked the packages and that seems to have fixed it! The images sort, but I have one other issue: all of my image files, post sorting, are now showing up as zero bytes in size, with an error stating that the file is empty when I try opening the image.

Comment: I closed out the workspace just to make sure, and tried it on a different folder of copied images. It seems to have fixed itself! Thank you so much!

Comment: I just checked with some toy files too myself, and it should work properly. I'm glad to have been able to help you.